# Can't use int array from Form1 in Form2

Tags: c#

I have an int array in `Form1` that I need to use in `Form2`. But when I'm trying to use the array values in `Form2`, it gives me zeros.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1 = new Form1();

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    {
       label1.Text += frm1.theCode[i];
    }
}
```

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/b4cf2b.png]

But when I try the same thing in Form1, it works great!

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frm2 = new Form2();

   for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) frm2.label1.Text += theCode[i]+ " ";

   frm2.Show();
}
```

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/jujthi.png]

But I still need to use the array in `Form2`, not `Form1`

Comment: It's almost definitely because your constructor does not fill `theCode` with values. `new Form1()` does *not* give you a pointer to the current form on the screen. It creates a **new** one.

Comment: What form does the first code belong to? You are assigning the values to the current form's `label1`, not `frm1`'s. In the second case, you are actually modifying `frm2`'s label, so that's why it works.

Comment: the first code belongs to Form2. How should I edit the code to make it work proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Form1` you must declare int array as static field and public in order to access it from another form.

So this is how you declare `theCode` in `Form1`

```
public static int[] theCode; // should be public and static
```

And this is how you use the array in `Form2`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // no need to create new instance of Form1.
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    {
       label1.Text += Form1.theCode[i]; // use the static field
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, needing to do this at all means that you have done it horribly wrong (and this is *hightly* error prone in production code/systems). Far better would be to simply separate your logic from your view and pass it around.